# Xamarin. SetContentView() in FormsAppCompatActivity throws unhandled exception

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-appcompat

When atempting to run this code in a xamarin forms app, I get the following exception:

**Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x1**

```
[Activity(Label = "Xamarin Forms", Icon = "@drawable/icon", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : FormsAppCompatActivity
{

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.main); 
        Toolbar toolbar = this.FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
        SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);           

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
...
```

If I inherit from AppCompatActivity instead the app does not crash but the forms apis are not available any more.

Here is my layout file in case it helps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using Android style toolbars? Can you switch to Forms toolbars?

Comment: Hi joe, I'm not sure... I'm new to the ecosystem and still getting my bearings. I was following [this blogpost](https://blog.xamarin.com/material-design-for-your-xamarin-forms-android-apps/) which results in the drawer navigation being overlayed over the top of the toolbar, I was then trying to use a custom layout to set my drawer navigation below the toolbar when i ran into the above problem. It could be thats it's not yet supported by forms? Cheers

Comment: I did successfully implement that blog post a while ago, and did not get that Exception. It should be supported by Forms. I'm just guessing right now, but could you try the values-v21/style.xml in the values-v22 and values-v23 folder?

Comment: Hi Joe, tried but to no avail. I think I'll just leave it for now since it's not critical. Thanks for your help, cheers!

Comment: Do you find a solution ?

Comment: I pretty sure we did but I'm afraid i can't remember what we did just know. If you're ok with waiting I'll have a look tomorrow and let you know

Comment: @flchaux looks like we ended up using XlabsFormsApp, using the code in this [example](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/54c6660ff62011a2c8a9c82512eb090edfaeb199/src/Forms/XLabs.Forms.Droid/XFormsApp.cs) And then having MainActivity inherit from XFormsApplicationDroidCompat like so: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/GeeWizWow/e41a85b6800e3ad1dcdecc9c8b7391dd)